# What version of git runs on gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit

When doing code reviews, I noticed that cherry-picking a patch through the gerrit Web UI throws merge conflicts, whereas if I do it locally on my machine, it works just fine. So, I was wondering if the git version running on gerrit is older than the one I have on my system. How can I find out the git version running on gerrit? Is there something I can do (for instance, submitting a patch that includes a command to catch the git version running on the git server, or something like that) to find out?

Comment: In the local repo Git records the conflict solutions, so if another similar conflict happens again in the same repo, it can be solved automatically. Another possibility is that your local branch is behind or ahead of or even diverged with the branch in the server, which has conflicts with the one you want to cherry-pick, while your local branch is okay with that one.

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit uses [JGit](https://eclipse.org/jgit/) which is a pure Java library Git implementation.

To know which JGit version your Gerrit is using, see the Gerrit release notes, for example: [Gerrit 2.12 Release Notes](https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/ReleaseNotes/ReleaseNotes-2.12.html#_upgrades)